# For finite groups, $[F(G),E(G)]=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $F(G)$ be the Fitting subgroup of $G$ and $E(G)$ be the layer of G (subgroup generated by components of $G$). Then $[F(G),E(G)]=1$.

**My attempt:** Since $E(G)$ is in particular a component of $G$ and $F(G)$ is a subnormal (actually, normal) subgroup of $G$, we must have $E(G)\subseteq F(G)$ or $[F(G),E(G)]=1$.

---

I don't know how to show that $E(G)\subseteq F(G)$ cannot happen.

Comment: If $E(G)$ is nontrivial then it is not solvable, but $F(G)$ is nilpotent, so we cannot have $E(G) \le F(G)$. But I have no idea how you concluded that $E(G) \le F(G)$ or $[F(G),E(G)]=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt From 6.5.2 in Kurzweil and Stellmacher, if $K$ is a component of $G$ and $U$ is subnormal in $G$, then $K\subseteq U$ or $[U,K]=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt By definition, components are non-trivial. So $E(G)$ must be non-trivial. If $E(G)\subseteq F(G)$, then $E(G)$ must be nilpotent, hence solvable. In particular, components can't be perfect, which is a contradiction. Correct?

Comment: It is not true that $E(G)$ must be nontrivial. $E(G)$ is trivial when there are no components.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway, if $E(G)=1$, then $[F(G),E(G)]=[F(G),1]=1$, so that's anyway not a problem.